# Powershell: Copy files to another folder by appending filenames as parent folder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy a bunch of files from a folder to another remote folder by renaming the files as the source folder name. The script I wrote works, but it is creating folders by appending the folder name as the parent, instead of copying the actual files itself.

```
$source = 'C:\Users\testserver\Desktop\WSVC1'

$destination = 'C:\Users\testserver\Documents\Powershell test'


$files = Get-ChildItem -File $source -Filter *.txt -Recurse -Force 


foreach ($file in $files) {

    $newPath = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $file-$(Split-Path -Path $source -Leaf)

    Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $newPath
}
```

Comment: For the `-ChildPath` you can use `$($File.Name)` and for the source path you should use `$($file.FullName)`. The only issue you could run into is when there is more than one file with the same name in your source folder structure.

Comment: Thank Olaf, It works :)

However, I am trying to copy the files without the.txt extension in between the new file name, i've tried "Copy-Item -Path $($file.BaseName) -Destination $newPath" but it does not really work.

Comment: I have also tried, ForEach-Object -Process {[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_)}, which work when added to the gci, however, i am now getting an error that the path is null.

Comment: Finally managed to solve it by tweaking the below :)

$newPath = Join-Path -Path "$destination" -ChildPath "$($file.BaseName)-$(Split-Path -Path $source -Leaf).txt" 

Thanks again olaf !

Comment: Using `$($File.BaseName)` for the `-ChildPath` parameter should have worked as well. ;-)